# UICollectionView insert cells on each side of a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to animate insertion in a horizontal, single row UICollectionView.  Say the cells look like this....

```
            c3    c6    c9    c12
```

and I want to insert cells around c6 like this...

```
c3    c4    c5 <<-c6->> c7    c8    c9    c12
```

So I have to challenges: (a) to have c6 to remain in the same position (at the same contentOffset) throughout the animation, and (b) to have the new cells to begin their insertion animation at c6's content offset and spread out.

The approach I've tried is (a) to move the content offset when I start the animation, and for (b) in a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass, try to answer the right layout attributes in `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath`.

Here's what that looks like...

```
// in the vc that has the collection view.
- (void)insertAroundIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger index = indexPath.row;

    // code here to insert items in my model array, two on each side of indexPath
    NSArray *indexPaths = // code here to compute the index paths of new items
    // I've tested the above and it works 

    // move the content offset
    CGFloat itemWidth = [self paddedItemSize].width;
    CGFloat offsetDelta = 2.0 * itemWidth;  // since we are inserting 2 items
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
    CGPoint newContentOffset = CGPointMake(contentOffset.x + offsetDelta, contentOffset.y);

    // will set the contentOffset to newContentOffset, but first...
    // record the layoutAttributes of the place where insertion is happening
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    // this is a property on my vc
    self.insertionLayoutAttributes = [layout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // do the insertion
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    // change the content offset
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:newContentOffset animated:NO];
}
```

The layout asks my view controller for the insertion attributes like this (I've never extended a protocol like this, but I checked that the control flows as I expect in the debugger)...

```
// my CollectionViewFlowLayout.h

@interface CollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
@end

@protocol CollectionViewLayoutDelegate <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)insertionLayoutAttributes;
@end

// my CollectionViewFlowLayout.m

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {
    id<CollectionViewLayoutDelegate> delegate = (id<CollectionViewLayoutDelegate>)self.collectionView.delegate;
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [delegate insertionLayoutAttributes];
    return (attributes)? attributes : [super initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
}
```

It makes sense, right?  The `contentOffset` thing works, but not quite.  The cell I want to remain fixed ends up in the same place, but it disappears first, as the collection view animates space opening for the new cells (I don't see why it should).

And the insertion starting position doesn't work at all.  No matter how I order things, the new cells (and the cell that was the center of the insertion) enter from the left side of the collection view.

When I inspect `attributes` in the debugger, the `origin.x` value looks correct, but the animation is all mixed up.  Any ideas appreciated.